# Does pandas-gbq currently support parameterised queries?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I need to create a simple ETL pipeline in Python using Pandas/pandas-gbq, reading each day between a given date range from BigQuery into a Pandas dataframe and create separate daily tables from query result (writing back to BigQuery).

Though there may be better and more efficient approaches (note: I'm not a software engineer), I'm currently looking into [Parameterized Queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bigquery_query_params_named-console) in BigQuery to parameterize date column and iterate this in a for-loop in Python.

Does anyone know if pandas-gbq currently supports Parameterized Queries? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The answer posted by [Ben P](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59373862/3887342) needs some improvements with **Pandas GBQ** as we get the error below:

> GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 POST
>   https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my-bigquery/jobs:
>   Missing query parameter value

The important and missing configuration parameter is:

```
'parameterValue': {'value': 'TX'}
```

which can be checked in [Running a query with a configuration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#query-config) docs sample.

Keeping the query config together we get:

```
query_config = {
    'query': {
        'parameterMode': 'NAMED',
        'queryParameters': [
            {
                'name': 'state',
                'parameterType': {'type': 'STRING'},
                'parameterValue': {'value': 'TX'}
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

I think this will help most of us who are coming to get the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does. However, I would recommend you make the switch to the official Google BigQuery Client Library, which also supports parameters.

BigQuery Client Libraries:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

**Setting parameters with Pandas GBQ**

You can set parameters in an Pandas GBQ query using the `configuration` parameter, to quote from the [Pandas GBQ docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_gbq.html):

> configuration : dict, optional Query config parameters for job
>   processing. For example:
>
> `configuration = {‘query’: {‘useQueryCache’: False}}`

Here is a full code example from that link which describes how you can parameterize a query in Pandas GBQ:

```
import pandas

sql = """
    SELECT name
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
    WHERE state = @state
"""
query_config = {
    'query': {
        'parameterMode': 'NAMED',
        'queryParameters': [
            {
                'name': 'state',
                'parameterType': {'type': 'STRING'}
            },
        ]
    }
}
df = pandas.read_gbq(sql, configuration=query_config)
```

**Setting parameters with the BigQuery Client Library**

Here is an excellent article on migrating from Pandas-GBQ to the BigQuery Client Library:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration

And here is some sample Python code where I use parameters in a query using the official BQ Client Library:

```
table_name = "my_table"
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
# Set the destination table
table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_name)
job_config.destination = table_ref
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'
sql = """
SELECT * FROM dataset.table WHERE visit_date = date
"""
query_params = [bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('date', 'DATE', date)]
job_config.query_parameters = query_params

# Start the query, passing in the extra configuration.
query_job = client.query(
    sql,
    location='EU',
    job_config=job_config)  # API request - starts the query

query_job.result()  # Waits for the query to finish
```

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Similarly, how can we pass a list inside query_config?

Comment: Can you explain more about why you recommend switching to the official Google BQ Client Library?  "I would recommend you make the switch to the official Google BigQuery Client Library"

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is to make use of  .to_dataframe()

```
df = client.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()
```

Please refer to the docs below.

[Download query results to DataFrame](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-results-dataframe)

[Google Cloud Client Libraries for google-cloud-bigquery](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client)

Following is a sample code -

```
name = 'John'

project_id = 'bqproject'
dataset_id = 'bqdataset'
table = 'bqtable'

query =  """SELECT * FROM `%s.%s.%s` WHERE Name = @name"""%(project_id,dataset_id,table)

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    query_parameters=[
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("name", "STRING", name),
        
        ]
    )

df = client.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()
df
```